# Remove the language prefix from the file URL

Tags: views, 6, files, i18n-l10n

We have a multilingual site on Drupal 6. which seems to work fine, we created a rotor view on the default language (en). This views looks great on default language which loads without any language prefix on url.

But when we switch to any other language (example fr) the views images doesn't load because the file path it queries for is prefixed with language code. I have tried the same on drupal 7 it works outof the box. But not sure if we can do this in drupal 6. I have tried couple of module like pathologic, redirect module but doesn't seem to help in my case.

```
File path for default language: example.com/sites/all/files/test.jpg

File path for other language:  example.com/fr/sites/all/files/test.jpg  [which doesn't exists on server]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue now, since the site was on **nginx**, I have written the redirect rule which removes language prefix while fetching files.

Insert this line in your server configuration:

```
rewrite ^/fr(/.*)$ $1 last;
```

If your site is on **Apache** you can add redirect rule on your server configuration or on `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ $1
```